# adding alias row in select query using union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `student(name_std,age_std,address_std)`. When i write query

```
select * from Student
```

it displays

```
name_std  age_std  address_std
Deepak     22        London
Anjali     16        Srilanka
```

My requirement is that when I query `select * from Student`,It should give me output like

```
name_std  age_std  address_std
**Name       Age       Address**   <<alias row>>
Deepak     22        London
Anjali     16        Srilanka
```

please suggest me some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `UNION` like below :

```
SELECT 'Name' as name_std,'Age' as age_std, 'Address' as address_std FROM dual
UNION
SELECT name_std,to_char(age_std),address_std FROM Student
```

Comment: To me, it adds them at the end.. how can I make sure the header is added in the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `alias` to each column to achieve your desired output.

```
SELECT name_std as Name age_std as Age address_std  as Address
FROM Student
```

Comment: I want original Column name plus my alias name in new row

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do away with `*` and use the column names and aliases

```
SELECT name_Std "Name", age_std "Age", address_std "Address"
FROM   student
```

Comment: Then go with what Upendra has posted as solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming age_std as number -

```
SELECT 'Name'    name_std, 
       'Age'     age_std, 
       'Address' address_std 
FROM   dual 
UNION ALL 
SELECT name_std, 
       To_char(age_std), 
       address_std 
FROM   student;
```